# how to set header and skiprows sparsely in read_excel()

Tags: pandas

[image]

This is my sample external excel file.
I want to set the header(column name) on the 3rd row and read the values starting from the 5th row.

`pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, header = [2], skiprows=3)`

I tried to using `hedaer` and `skiprows` but fail to read correctly.

Is it impossible to do this simultineously when I read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the `skiprows` argument in a list.

```py
from pandas import read_excel

df = read_excel('foo.xlsx', header=[2], skiprows=[3])

print(df)
```

Results in:

```
   Unnamed: 0  aapl  msft
0           1     2     3
1           4     5     6
```

Giving a number `n` means  "skip `n` rows", giving a list with numbers means "skip these indices".

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=[0, 1, 3])
```